# How to make a text below icons in a Row and make Row start at the bottom of the screen (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

So im trying to make an icon button with 2x3 stuff, where there are 2 rows of 3 elements across a screen. However when im implementing this with row the text is on the right side of the icon, I would like to make the text below the icon

Currently What is have is this

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Column (children: <Widget>[

        Row(


          //row1
          children: [
            IconButton(
              iconSize: 70.0,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add_chart, color: Colors.greenAccent),
              tooltip: 'My Learning',
            ),
            Text('My Learning',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange)
            ),

            IconButton(
              iconSize: 60.0,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline, color: Colors.greenAccent),
              tooltip: 'Deep 46',
            ),
            Text('Deep 46',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange)
            ),
            IconButton(
              iconSize: 60.0,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.flight, color: Colors.greenAccent),
              tooltip: 'unleashed',
            ),
            Text('More Unleashed',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange)
            ),

          ],
        ),

        Row(
          children: [

            IconButton(
              iconSize: 60.0,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.videogame_asset_outlined, color: Colors.greenAccent),
              tooltip: 'learning game',
            ),
            Text('Learning Game',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange)
            ),

            IconButton(
              iconSize: 60.0,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.access_time, color: Colors.greenAccent),
              tooltip: 'absen',
            ),
            Text('Absen',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange)
            ),
            IconButton(
              iconSize: 60.0,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_today, color: Colors.greenAccent),
              tooltip: 'event',
            ),
            Text('Event',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
                textAlign: TextAlign.end
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ]
        )
    );

  }
```

Which outputs something that looks like:

[image]

How can i make the text below the icons, also if anyone knows how do i make the row or icon start at the bottom of the screen.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap icon and text with Column:

[EDITED]

```
Column(
  children[
    Expanded(child: Container()),
    Row(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            IconButton(
              iconSize: 70.0,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add_chart, color: Colors.greenAccent),
              tooltip: 'My Learning',
            ),
            Text('My Learning',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange)
            ),
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, do you also know how i can make the row start at the bottom of the screen , cus the row is starting at the top of the screen for me

Comment: updated answer, add expanded widget before row

Answer (score 0):

So you can use "**Column**" widget that will solve your problem.

For example,

```
  column(
     children: <widget>[
         IconButton(
          iconSize: 70.0,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.add_chart, color: Colors.greenAccent),
          tooltip: 'My Learning',
        ),
        Text('My Learning',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange)
        )
     ]
  )
```

*Note*: Inside your row widget you can make this Column widget as your direct children then wrap your IconButton and text into the Column widget.
I hope it will help you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, do know how i can make the row start at the bottom of the screen , because the row is starting at the top of the screen for me